# How to convert content:// uri into a file path?

Tags: android, uri, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to select a pdf file from drive and upload it to firebase storage. When I select a pdf file from external storage it works fine but it doesn't work when i try to select a file from drive. This is because of the content:// uri i obtain from drive which is not supported. Is there a way to convert this uri to file path. If not what might be other relevant solutions?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("pdf/*");

intent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, true);startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {uri = data.getData();

String stringUri = uri.toString();
String fileFormat = "pdf";
Log.d("Pdf Uri",stringUri);final DatabaseReference dataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

final StorageReference filepath = storageRefr.child(root_child).child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putFile(uri);


uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
@Override
public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
throw task.getException();
}

// Continue with the task to get the download URL
return filepath.getDownloadUrl();
}
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
//do something
}
```

This is the uri I obtain from drive: `content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.9HYx5b%0A`

Required uri is :

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/file.pdf
```

Comment: This is just a partial answer. Since you're trying to upload not from your computer, I think you have to convert the drive api file to a blob and upload using [Upload from a Blob or File](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files).